# Can we get something that says 'Verification email sent' when registering?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, sign-up, email-verification

I recently just registered for a Stack Exchange account through this site (http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  When I registered, nothing happened (the form doesn't redirect), so I registered 4 more times, and finally I decided to check my email.

I had 5 emails from **do-not-reply@stackexchange.com!**  I think this site is confusing many people by not telling them to check their emails.  I know this isn't just because of my browser's cache, because I cleared my browser's cache and tried registering again (for the 2nd time), and the same thing happened.

Can we get something like this when successfully registering?

[image: Verification email sent]

Comment: Related: [New login page thinks I created an account even when it fails](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218153/new-login-page-thinks-i-created-an-account-even-when-it-fails).  This would be a dup if the issue you are describing wasn't reported in the comments

Comment: There certainly _is_ a confirmation page - what browser and OS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a bug in the success path for the signup form - it was not displaying the correct page.

This has been corrected - after a successful signup, you will get a confirmation page telling you to check your email.